Slater determinant with complex coefficient
Suppose we have a system of three particles with states $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. We can write a state of the form (up to a normalization factor ):
\begin{eqnarray}
\Psi=|\alpha,\beta,\gamma\rangle + e^{i\theta}|\alpha,\gamma,\beta\rangle + e^{i\theta}|\beta,\alpha,\gamma\rangle+|\beta,\gamma,\alpha\rangle + |\gamma,\alpha,\beta\rangle+e^{i\theta}|\gamma,\beta,\alpha\rangle.
\end{eqnarray}
Upon permutation of any particle pairs, calling $\Pi$ the permutation operator, we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Pi \Psi = e^{-i\theta}\Psi^*,
\end{eqnarray}
which is only an eigenvalue equation for $\theta=0,\pi$  because the coefficients are real in that case; the case $\theta=\pi$ gives the Slater determinant for fermions. However in any case $\Pi^2\Psi = \Psi$ as one would expect, independent of $\theta$. Can the state written above be considered a valid generalization of a Slater determinant for particles whose exchange statistics correspond neither to fermions nor bosons? If not, what would be the appropiate treatment to generate such a state on a first quantization description?

if a single interchange leads to multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$ as from $|\alpha,\beta,\gamma\rangle$ to $e^{i\theta}|\alpha,\gamma,\beta\rangle$ to represent $\beta \rightleftharpoons \gamma,$ as you seem to assume, then why don't you write the 4th term as $e^{i2\theta}|\beta,\gamma, \alpha\rangle$ to represent $\alpha \rightleftharpoons \beta$?

Terms picking a phase correspond to odd permutations in the string $\alpha\beta\gamma$, whereas the ones with 1 correspond to even permutations. This way of writing the state is to make it explicit, so that in the permutation group of N ordered integers, one can always consider a split between "even" permutations and "odd" permutations. But besides that, it is just a substitution of the "-1" encountered in the Slater determinant by a complex number.
